# When should I be using Photoshop to create a webpage?

Tags: photoshop

I am a starter of web design and Photoshop, and I just watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wThxAavkYXA) which shows how to create a webpage using Photoshop. Just wondering when and why Photoshop should be used to create a webpage. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Juhana Thanks for the comment. I see how tricky it could be. But still, is it the standard or best way to create a webpage layout?

Comment: No, I'd say CSS & HTML in a text editor is the standard way. The best way is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your design and esthetics demand is very high. Creating sites with photoshop enables to easy develop beautiful designs but pretty much heavy (in terms of many images, complex layouts and so on). What the majority of good web designers do is create a wireframe with photoshop and then adapt it to CSS & HTML.

Comment: Slightly better than my answer which was going to be 'never' :) Use PS for editing and manipulating your images sure, but as part of the workflow for creating the web page? I don't think so...

Comment: I agree with you @Spacedman, but after see how great designers work at Interbrand and other big companies like that, they always use PS first to get an idea of what they're trying to do. I mean, we're developers, give us notepad and is enough, but design is pretty different.

Comment: The video shows how photoshop could be used to slice the layout. It's pretty much simple, like WYSIWYG, but like the stuff got done using Dreamweaver, I again find bad layout practice in the source code, which shows that the layout is actualized using table tags.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see it's a great way for easy designing task.

Comment: @xczzhh You're welcome, if you wan't some prebuilt Photoshop textures and templates (beautiful, indeed), see http://designmoo.com/, there are free.

Comment: @Randolf Thank you again, very beautiful web layouts design indeed! OH, and, is this actually the difference between a web designer and a developer, i.e., the designer portrays on Photoshop how a webpage is going to look like, and the developer actualizes the idea using code??

Answer (score 0):

You could use photoshop - we have an in house designer here who does it.

But I do know of some software from [softandGUI](http://www.softandgui.co.uk/) will let you wireframe and prototype websites. You can also use it to design apps for iPhones, Tablets, Android, Apps, aswell.